# How would I check this javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
{
    "@": {
        "xmlns": "http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"
    },
    "SendEmailResult": {
        "MessageId": "0000012fdd10caaf-021c6e9e-e872-4b35-ad94-1d11c79a6324-000000"
    },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "736d5bb2-7b7d-11e0-b435-f7b0c9315f0d"
    }
}
```

How do I check if "MessageId" exists in a object? (without throwing errors)
I might get other json objects returned, and I need to know if the one I get has a "MessageId".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference to it in `obj`, then:

```
if (obj && obj.SendEmailResult && "MessageId" in obj.SendEmailResult) {
    // The "MessageId" property exists in `obj.SendEmailResult`
}
```

Probably more usefully, though:

```
var msgid = obj && obj.SendEmailResult && obj.SendEmailResult.MessageId;
if (msgid) {
    // The property exists and is "truthy", `msgid` is the value
}
```

JavaScript's AND operator `&&` is more useful than that of some other languages, it returns the right-hand side's *value* if both of its operands are "truthy" (rather than just returning a `true` / `false` result, as in most languages). A "truthy" value is a value that is not "falsy" (obviously). "Falsy" values are `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, and `0`.

So the above basically says "Set `msgid` to `obj.SendEmailResult.MessageId` provided that `obj` and `obj.SomeEmailResult` both exist.

(The `||` operator is [similarly powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).)

Comment: +1 What about using `obj.SendEmailRequest.hasOwnProperty('MessageId')` to protect against [this rarity](http://jsfiddle.net/RxPF5/)?

Comment: @alex: Sure, if appropriate. 99% of the time, you don't care, you just want the property -- wherever it comes from. :-) (And you want to run far, far away from any code that extends `Object.property`.)

Comment: J. People that do it should be introduced to people who assign a  different value to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the result in a variable called result, you should be able to do this with a simple if statement (considering that the javascript if statement short circuits:

```
if (result && result["SendEmailResult"] && result["SendEmailResult"]["MessageId"]) {
    //execute your code
}
```